Railing and gate around basement egress stairs
Hi all, hoping to get some advice on the most straightforward way to put up a (preferably code compliant) PVC or composite railing and gate around the stairwell for my basement egress door.
The slate slabs on top of the walls of the well overhang by 2.5” over the outer edges and 1” over the front edge. It is 82” long.

Do I use side mounted posts? I can’t find side mounts that will clear the 2.5” lateral overhang of the slate so I don’t know if this is an option. I could mount to the house I suppose, but don’t know if there is a corner mount bracket that would clear the overhang at the other end, and would still need another point of support in the middle to avoid going over 6 feet between posts. Is there a way to side mount with the overhang that I have?

Do I install top mounted posts by drilling through the slate and counter sinking a concrete anchor into the concrete below the slate? Wondering if this is a secure way to fasten the post and if the slate will be prone to cracking.


2b. If going top mount, how do I install a gate that is not too high off the ground? Can I use a gate that is taller than the side railing and attach it to the top mounted posts? I imagine this would cause clearance issues on the hinge side. Or do I need to install posts for the gate in front of the well?
Appreciate any guidance!

What is the purpose of the fence?  How are the walls of the stairwell, and the building constructed? are you OK with trimming the slate ? how wide are the stairs? is the slate cemented in place or loose?

Your two ideas suggest you're interested in mounting the rails and gate to the cement/blocks/stone of the stairwell. What about stand-alone posts & railing in the dirt next to the stairwell? Then no need to alter the stairwell.

@Jasen - purpose is to keep my young kids from falling down the stairwell. Stairwell looks like it’s made out of concrete with a layer of smooth cement at the surface. Building is cement from what I can see outside but not sure what’s underneath. The stairs are 41” wide. I’d be ok with trimming the slate but have no idea how I’d do that. The slabs are cemented in place though one of them has come loose and is mobile.

@Triplefault, do you mean into the dirt directly or by pouring a new concrete column on the side? I wouldn’t think directly into dirt would be stable enough over time and I was hoping to avoid pouring more concrete.

@GreenScrubs I didn't have a particular method in mind, only using usual methods to put railing poles and gate just beyond the stairwell structure.

IMO only coring into the steps and putting posts in there will keep kids from falling.  If you put posts into the slate at the top, they could still walk along the inside edge of the slate.

@Huesmann there would be a gate so they wouldn’t be able to get into the stairwell at all.

@GreenScrubs then there's no reason you can't simply drive fence posts into the soil...
